# What transitive verbs are there for when someone ignores your attempts to contact them?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, business-language, register

I’m looking for transitive verbs that might fill in the blank in these sentences: *We’ve been sending him emails every week, but he’s ___ed us*, *We’ve been sending him emails every week, but he’s ___ing us*.

The most obvious verb is *ignore*, and there may be more colorful options (*he’s cold-shouldering us*, *he’s given us the brush-off*) but I can’t shake the feeling that there is a nice monosyllabic verb along the lines of *to snub*, *to ditch*, *to stiff*.

EDIT: I’m not interested in situations like the one in which one person is giving another “the silent treatment” or being passive-aggressive in person. I’m mainly interested in professional situations where someone has fallen out of contact (although slangy and informal verbs are still welcome). This point seems to distinguish my question from the associated question.

EDIT #2: The associated question is about “the ‘intentional ignoring’ of someone”, “ignoring another person's behaviour”, and “acting uninterested in talking or communicating” and it appears to be about personal relations and how one behaves in someone’s presence. My question is about ignoring someone’s attempts to contact you, the leading example is email, and (as I said in the previous edit) I’m mainly interested in professional situations.

Comment: The question labelled as a duplicate described a different situation, but some of the answers do apply. Is there a reason why none of those answers apply? Closing the questions doesn't delete it, it directs people to provide answers in a single spot.